# Pyinstaller Packed EXE failed to run script on other PC. says: Qt5Core,dll not found

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

The produced app.exe from the code below starts OK on my PC, but failed to start on other computers (all windows 10). It can't run it because of fatal error. Failed to run script. The command line says: Qt5core.dll could not be found.
I looked inside dist folder and the .dll file is there.

I used very simple script that show only an empty form.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Pyinstaller: 3.5
PyQT5: 5.13

What is the problem?

Comment: How you build your app? Which version of PyQt5 you use? Please provide minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: Also, which version of Pyinstaller did you use?

Comment: Other question: are you certain that the error message says **Qt5code.dll**? Or was it perhaps **Qt5Core.dll** instead?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution [HERE](https://blog.japinli.top/2019/07/21/pyinstaller-package-pyqt5-error-on-Qt5Core/), but i'm not sure if it is safe. It is by removing two line of code from `site-packages\PyQt5\__init__.py` file

I commented these two lines:

```
        else:
            raise ImportError("unable to find Qt5Core.dll on PATH")
```